# php if statement not working properly

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm not sure why, but some blank values still filter through my `if` statement... As when I do echo a json encoded version, some values have "keys" but "values" do not contain anything. Any thoughts?

```
function graph_fees($competitors, $fee_graph_data){

        foreach ($competitors as $competitor) {
            if (!empty($competitor->minSingleCareFee)) {
                $fee_graph_data[$competitor->Home_name] = $competitor->minSingleCareFee;
            } 
        }
        return $fee_graph_data;     
    }


$mm_fees = graph_fees($competitors, $fee_graph_data);
echo json_encode($mm_fees);
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($competitor->minSingleCareFee);` output? Add it inside the `foreach` (outside the `if` statement).

Comment: They could be `null` and if you echo `null` it won't be visible.

Comment: if "blanks" getting through then there not blank.. try trim() before the if

Comment: @LozCherone so you mean something like:

if(!empty(trim($competitor->SingleCareFee)) ??

Comment: no you cant do that, do it before the if

Comment: Yep, that's what he means.  If there's a single space character (or any other whitespace) it'll fail `empty()`

Comment: Oh, right, you can't put a function return inside an `empty()` call... it'll yell at you if you try.

Comment: @LozCherone So I need to loop once to trim everything and then feed it to the if statement?

Comment: @Jason: Since PHP 5.5, you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whitespace may of creeped in when creating the data, trim() it before your check.

```
<?php 
function graph_fees($competitors, $fee_graph_data = array())
{
    foreach ($competitors as $competitor) {
        $competitor->Home_name = trim($competitor->Home_name);
        $competitor->minSingleCareFee = trim($competitor->minSingleCareFee);

        if (!empty($competitor->minSingleCareFee) && !empty($competitor->Home_name)) {
            $fee_graph_data[$competitor->Home_name] = $competitor->minSingleCareFee;
        }
    }
    return $fee_graph_data;
}


$mm_fees = graph_fees($competitors, $fee_graph_data);
echo json_encode($mm_fees);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($competitors as $competitor) {
        $myValue = trim($competitor->minSingleCareFee);
        if (!empty($myValue)) {
            $fee_graph_data[$competitor->Home_name] = $competitor->minSingleCareFee;
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A string containing blanks is not empty. As of php doc:

> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> ```
> "" (an empty string)
> 0 (0 as an integer)
> 0.0 (0 as a float)
> "0" (0 as a string)
> NULL
> FALSE
> array() (an empty array)
> $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
> ```

so, if things fall through your if, `$competitor->minSingleCareFee` does contain *something*.

Try

```
if ( isset($competitor->minSingleCareFee) 
             && trim($competitor->minSingleCareFee) != false ) {
```

which will skip values like `"     "` or `"\n"`